# How can we store data in two different database at a time using Hibernate?

Tags: hibernate

Interviewer question to me:

How can we store data in two different database at a time using Hibernate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure but this can be possible:

1. Make 2 hibernate.cfg.xml
2. In HibernateUtil class where you build your sessionFactory object. Build 2 SessionFactory object. Make getter methods of both sessionFactory object.
3. Where you want to insert some data take appropriate sessionFactory object and do the operation.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is any built-in feature of Hibernate, but you can either:

1. Use 2 SessionFactories, but you
   can then hardly define it as "at a
   time"
2. Use Hibernate interceptor
   that will do changes to the other
   database when some entity is changed
3. Use JPA events (which I believe
   use interceptors under the hood)

Answer (score 0):

In my experience, example for `two or more databases from same data source`

**Main database** : hibernate.cfg.xml

```
<property name="hibernate.connection.url">
    jdbc:mysql://ip_adress:3306/main_db
</property>
```

**Alternate database** : domain class

```
@Table(catalog = "alt_db", name = "table_name") // Specify catalog

@Table(catalog = "alt_db2", name = "table_name")
```